# #heremaps How to get data in info-bubble when clicking on the Cluster in javascript

Tags: javascript, here-maps-rest, heremaps

I have some clustering on the here-map. I want when I click on the particular cluster then I need the data on the clicked cluster.

In here-map How to get data in the info-bubble when clicking on the Cluster in javascript?

Comment: You need to add an event listener to the cluster. Check this answer it is very similar to what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808876/here-maps-zoom-on-cluster-click

Comment: I am getting latitude and longitude when I am clicking on the particular clustering but in the data key, I am getting data: undefined.

Comment: I suggest you to update your question and share your code, otherwise it is highly unlikely that someone can help you